# CFloop query to store multiple values in database

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfloop

I have few variables that contain multiple values. Basically I want to store all the values into my database. I am using this code which I got here in Stackoverflow.

```
<cfquery datasource="databaseName">

INSERT INTO spreadsheet 
    ([Local.Time.Stamp],
    [Energy.Delivered..kVAh.],
    [Energy.Received..kVAh.],
    [Energy.Received..kVARh.],
    [Energy.Delivered..kVARh.],
    [Real.A..kW.],
    [Real.B..kW.])

    VALUES
    (<cfloop query="excelquery">
    '#excelquery.col_1#',
    '#excelquery.col_2#',
    '#excelquery.col_3#',
    '#excelquery.col_4#',
    '#excelquery.col_5#',
    '#excelquery.col_6#',
    '#excelquery.col_7#'
    </cfloop>)

</cfquery>
```

However I always get a syntax error. I believe that my `cfloop` part is wrong, can someone please tell me the correct way for me to write that cfloop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the generated query not `cfloop` i.e., for entering multiple values the format should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (col,col,...) VALUES (val,val,...),(val,val,...),...
```

Also, use [`cfqueryparam`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) to avoid sql injection.

You can try this:

```
<cfquery datasource="databaseName">

  INSERT INTO spreadsheet 
    ([Local.Time.Stamp],
    [Energy.Delivered..kVAh.],
    [Energy.Received..kVAh.],
    [Energy.Received..kVARh.],
    [Energy.Delivered..kVARh.],
    [Real.A..kW.],
    [Real.B..kW.])

  VALUES
   <cfloop query="excelquery">

     <!--- cf_sql_varchar is just an example.  --->
     (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_1#">,
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_2#">,
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_3#">,
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_4#">,
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_5#">,
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_6#">,
      <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#excelquery.col_7#">) 
      #excelQuery.currentRow NEQ excelQuery.recordCount ? ',': ''#
    </cfloop>

</cfquery>
```

*You might have to add a recordCount check before generating the query to avoid errors for no records.*

Comment: i had no idea you could do this - #excelQuery.currentRow NEQ excelQuery.recordCount ? ',': ''# - i've always used cfif. nice!